# Log likelihood of one model simple

Tags: modeling, conditional-probability, cumulative-distribution-function, bivariate, likelihood

Let $(T_{1},T_{2})\sim N_{2}(\mu_{1},\mu_{2},\sigma_{1}\sigma_{2},\rho)$ and consider the model:

$$Y=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
T_{1},\quad \textrm{if}\quad U=1\\
\ \ 0,\ \ \ \ \textrm{if}\quad U=0
\end{array}\right.$$ where

$$U=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
1, \quad \textrm{if}\quad T_{2}>1\\
0, \quad \textrm{if}\quad T_{2}\leq 1
\end{array}\right.$$

therefore,

$P(U=u)=[1-\Phi_{T_{2}}\left(\frac{1-\mu_{2}}{\sigma_{2}}\right)]^{u}*[\Phi_{T_{2}}\left(\frac{1-\mu_{2}}{\sigma_{2}}\right)]^{(1-u)}, u=0,1$ and $\Phi_{T_{2}}$ is CDF $N(\mu_{2},\sigma_{2}).$

Then, the log-likelihood function for this model based on a single pair of observations (y, u) can be written as

$\mathcal{L}(\mu_{1},\mu_{2},\sigma_{1}\sigma_{2},\rho;y,u)=u\ln[f_{T_{1}|T_{2}>1}(y)P(U=1)]+(1-u)ln[P(U=0)].$

Is correct the log-likelihood above?

Besides that, is correct the deduction below:

\begin{eqnarray}
P(Y\leq y)&=&P(Y\leq y|U=1).P(U=1)+P(Y\leq y|U=0).P(U=0).(1(y=0))\\
&=&P(Y\leq y|U=1).P(U=1)+P(Y=0|U=0).P(U=0).(1(y=0))\\
&=&P(T_{1}\leq y|T_{2}>1).P(T_{2}>1)+1.P(T_{2}\leq1).(1(y=0))
\end{eqnarray}

Thus,

$f_{Y}(y)=f_{T_{1}|T_{2}>1}(y).P(T_{2}>1)+P(T_{2}\leq 1).(1(y=0)),$ where $.1(y=0)$ is a indicator function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likelihood can be written as
\begin{align}
L(\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\rho)&=P(U=u)f_{Y|U=u}(y)
\\&=\begin{cases}
\left(1-\Phi(\frac{1-\mu_2}{\sigma_2})\right)f_{T_1|T_2>1}(y)&\text{for }u=1\\
\Phi(\frac{1-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}) &\text{for }u=0
\end{cases}\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution.

Because $T_1$ and $T_2$ are correlated the distribution of $T_1$ given $T_2>1$ is a bit tricky.  We know that the opposite conditional distribution of $T_2$ given $T_1=t_1$ is normal with conditional expectation
$$E(T_2|T_1=t_1)=\mu_2 + \rho\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}(t_1-\mu_1)$$
and variance
$$\operatorname{Var}(T_2|T_1=t_1)=\sigma_2^2(1-\rho^2).$$

Using Bayes theorem, the conditional pdf of $T_1$ given $T_2>1$ needed in (1) is therefore
\begin{align}
f_{T_1|T_2>1}(t_1)&=\frac{P(T_2>1|T_1=t_1)f_{T_1}(t_1)}{P(T_2>1)}
\\&=\frac{\left(1-\Phi(\frac{1-\mu_2-\rho\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}(t_1-\mu_1)
}{\sigma_2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}})\right)\frac1{\sigma_1}\phi(\frac{t_1-\mu_1}{\sigma_1})}{1-\Phi(\frac{1-\mu_2}{\sigma_2})},
\end{align}
where $\phi$ is the pdf of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: Do you consider $P(Z_{2}>1|Z_{1}=z_{1})=P(Z_{2}>1|Z_{1}\leq z_{1})$ or am I mistaken?

Comment: No, those probabilities are not equal.

Comment: so there is a problem, because my question needs to solve $P(Z_{2}>1|Z_{1}\leq z_{1})$ or more specifically $P(Z_{1}\leq z_{1}|Z_{2}>1).$

Comment: You can compute such probabilities using the cumulative distribution function of the multivariate normal distribution (available as function `pmvnorm` in the `mvtnorm` R-package).  I believe this function is based on some form of numerical integration.

Comment: I understand, therefore your demonstration does not answer my question fully? I need to $P(Z_{1}\leq z_{1}|Z_{2}>1).$ But you it helped me a lot!